# Erro publicar apk na play store, certificados SHA1 estão diferentes

Tags: android, apk

Recentemente recebi  um e-mail do Google dizendo que agora havia suporte para compra de apps em Reais e que deveria migrar minha conta de desenvolvedor. Segui os passos como descrito no e-mail e todos os meus apps foram migrados para minha nova conta de desenvolvedor.

Porém, quando fiz o upload de um novo apk usando a mesma chave que sempre usei estou recebendo uma mensagem dizendo que o certificado SHA1 está diferente.
Já voltei backup da minha chave e continua ocorrendo o mesmo erro.

Alguns coisas que mudaram desde o último apk que eu havia carregado.

1. Versão do Eclipse (Estou usando atualmente a Luna Release 4.4.0)
   Build id: 20140612-0600)
2. Minha conta de desenvolvedor
3. Adicionei o `android-support-v7-appcompat` ao meu projeto (Segui o tutorial do próprio site do google developer)

Comment: A chave deve ser mantida quando for atualizada a aplicação e que com a perda do key talvez não tem como fazer um update do apk.

Comment: Mas eu não perdi minha key. Esse é o problema, eu continuo assinando meu apk com a mesma key. Até voltei um backup da key para garantir, mas continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Rafael, será que isso não é nenhum problema na sua nova conta? Já chegou a fazer algum contato com o suporte deles?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa resolver duas coisas:

1 - Mudar todos os nomes dos Packages do seu projeto e se possível o nome do projeto no mainfest xml

2 - Gerar uma nova Key

```
Isso é chato, mas resolve!
```